# Parameterized Geb module is not working in a certain situation

Tags: groovy, geb

I'm writing a Geb test and I want to use a parameterized module, but I can't seem to get it working.
This is my page object:

```
class CreateNewOrganizationPage extends Page {

    static url = "/organization/create"

    static content = {
        organizationTypes { module MultiSelect, id: "orgTypeIds" }           
    }
}
```

And this is my module:

```
class MultiSelect extends Module {
    def id

    static content = {
        caret {  $("#" + id + "-caret") }
    }
}
```

And this is how I use it in a test:

```
when:
to CreateNewOrganizationPage
organizationTypes.caret.click()
```

It seems to be the same as the situation on this site:
http://swalsh.org/blog/2014/06/25/groovy-browser-automation-with-geb/

What am I doing wrong here? Because I get the following exception in the stacktrace:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: geb.content.PageContentTemplateFactoryDelegate.module() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap, java.lang.Class) values: [[id:orgTypeIds], class pages.management.MultiSelect]
Possible solutions: module(java.lang.Class), module(java.util.Map, java.lang.Class), module(geb.Module), module(java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object), module(java.util.Map, java.lang.Class, geb.navigator.Navigator), dump()

    at geb.content.PageContentTemplateFactoryDelegate.module(PageContentTemplateFactoryDelegate.groovy:49)
    at pages.management.CreateNewOrganizationPage._clinit__closure1$_closure3(CreateNewOrganizationPage.groovy:43)
    at pages.management.CreateNewOrganizationPage._clinit__closure1$_closure3(CreateNewOrganizationPage.groovy)
    at geb.content.PageContentTemplate.invokeFactory(PageContentTemplate.groovy:97)
    at geb.content.PageContentTemplate.create_closure1(PageContentTemplate.groovy:59)
    at geb.content.PageContentTemplate.create_closure1(PageContentTemplate.groovy)
    at geb.content.PageContentTemplate.create(PageContentTemplate.groovy:82)
    at geb.content.PageContentTemplate.get(PageContentTemplate.groovy:54)
    at geb.content.DefaultPageContentSupport.getContent(DefaultPageContentSupport.groovy:42)
    at geb.content.PageContentSupport.propertyMissing(PageContentSupport.groovy:39)
    at geb.Page.propertyMissing(Page.groovy:112)
    at geb.Browser.propertyMissing(Browser.groovy:216)
    at geb.spock.GebSpec.propertyMissing(GebSpec.groovy:60)
    at ManagementSpec.create new organization(ManagementSpec.groovy:21)
```

**EDIT:**
Problem solved:

```
specialDatePicker { module(new DatePicker(id: "someId")) }
```

Now it works!

Comment: The code above works on geb version `0.13.1`. What version of geb you are using?

Comment: I'm using geb-core 1.1.1

Comment: And groovy 2.4.9 and selenium 3.0.1, although that's not really relevant I think.

Comment: I managed to get it working! I'll edit the OP.

Comment: I do not see the connection how the `DatePicker` comes into play, what is it and how does it solve the issue. Could you elaborate on this please? As to me it seams that the original question is missing information that could shed some light on the solution

Comment: The DatePicker is just an example I copy pasted from my code. I fixed it with `module(new Object(param: "someParam"))` instead of `module Object, param: "someParam"`